# jQuery UI autocomplete after input something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I want to autocomplete user name after input '@'(at sign).

form_html.erb:

```
  <div class="form-group ui-widget">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 5, placeholder: '...', class: 'form-control', id: "tags", 'data-article-id': @article.id.to_s %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is my coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  id = $("#tags").data("article-id")
  $("#tags").autocomplete
    source:  '/articles/' + id + '/autocomplete.json'
    minLength: 1
```

current appearance：

[image]

I want to input the "@"(at sign) then auto-complete user name.

Please tell me if you have good ideas, Thanks in advance!

Comment: just initial thought on keyup check length of textarea; if length = 1; prepend @sign with user entered value....

Comment: You can also at an @ symbol to each name in the json.

Comment: @BasvanStein you give me good ideas， thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bas van Stein suggestion, I can add @ sign to each name in json:

```
  def autocomplete
    @articles = Article.find_by(id: params[:article_id])
    @commentor_names = @articles.comments.map{|e| "@" + e.name}.uniq
                                         .map{|e| e if e.match(/^#{params[:term]}/i) }.compact
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {
        render json: @commentor_names
      }
    end
```

end

then appearance:

[image]

It can work, but inefficient, not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://blog.miroslavpopovic.com/2012/06/23/jqueryui-autocomplete-filter-words-starting-with-term/) you can do the job by customizing `$.ui.autocomplete.filter` function.